# digital root sort algorithm

Tags: javascript, algorithm, sorting

I'm running through challenges on codefight and all tests pass except 1 "hidden test" where I'm unable to see the test data inserted... **I'm looking for help pointing out what I'm missing or a failing test case with my solution.**

Problem:

> Digit root of some positive integer is defined as the sum of all of
>   its digits.
>
> You are given an array of integers. Sort it in such a way that if a
>   comes before b then the digit root of a is less than or equal to the
>   digit root of b. If two numbers have the same digit root, the smaller
>   one (in the regular sense) should come first. For example 4 and 13
>   have the same digit root, however 4 < 13 thus 4 comes before 13 in any
>   digitRoot sorting where both are present.
>
> Example
>
> For a = [13, 20, 7, 4], the output should be [20, 4, 13, 7].
>
> [time limit] 4000ms (js) [input] array.integer a
>
> Array of positive integers.
>
> [output] array.integer

My Solution:

```
function digitRootSort(a) {
    "use strict";

    function getDigitalRoot(n) {
        let _dr = n
            .toString()
            .split('')
            .reduce((acc, val, i) => {
                return acc += parseInt(val)
            }, 0)
            .toString()

        if (_dr.length > 1) {
            return getDigitalRoot(_dr)
        }

        return parseInt(_dr)
    }

    const digitalRootSorted = a.sort((a,b) => {
        const _a = getDigitalRoot(a)  
        const _b = getDigitalRoot(b)

        return _a < _b 
            ? -1 
            :  _a > _b
                ? 1
                : a < b 
                    ? -1
                    : a === b
                        ? 0
                        : 1
    })

    return digitalRootSorted
}
```

Comment: Wow, it's a big `getDigitalRoot` function, you could just write: `getDigitalRoot = n=> (n%9) || 9;`

Comment: Do you get any message other than 'hidden test failed' - e.g. could it be that your solution exceeds the time limit?

Comment: @WashingtonGuedes Your suggestion correctly computes digital roots up to 9 - everything above needs further processing.

Comment: @le_m above 9? I can't find an example

Comment: @WashingtonGuedes `getDigitalRoot(19)` should be `10` but your suggestion computes `1`

Comment: @le_m. And `10` gives you `1+0=1`

Comment: The OP function is recursive

Comment: @WashingtonGuedes According to OP's definition, the digital root of some positive integer is defined as the sum of all of its digits. The sum of all digits of 19 is 10, right? OP: Could this be the reason why your test case fails? Either your definition or your code is incorrect.

Comment: Proof of my function, in case the OP really wants a recursive approach: _http://www.sjsu.edu/faculty/watkins/Digitsum0.htm_

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could just sum the digits and use a chained approach, like

```js
const sum = n => [...n.toString()].reduce((a, b) => +a + +b),
      array = [13, 20, 7, 4];

array.sort((a, b) => sum(a) - sum(b) || a - b);

console.log(array);
```

Comment: const sum = n => [...n].reduce((a, b) => a + b); It will throw error as you cant use ... operator before number in array

Comment: @Gor, right, there was another error, too. thank you.

Comment: why there is diff between `a + b` and `+a + +b`?

Comment: @WeijingLin, a single plus is using the sign for the number as short conversion to number. a double pluss `++` without space is an [increment operator `++`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#Increment). The double plus with a space between is an addition operator and an [unary plus `+`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#Unary_plus) for the number.